# Is there a way for publisher(affiliates) to create their own affiliate link for their sellers?

Tags: javascript, cookies, token, affiliate, publisher

by any chance that there is any way for publishers (affiliates) to create their own affiliate link to their sellers without the help of an affiliate marketing platform out there?

For example, I have a seller who have a great interest on promoting their product via my channels(blog,social media) but they don't have affiliate marketing software nor join in any affiliate marketing platform(Awin etc..).

I was wondering whether I can make my own unique affiliate link between me with that seller so that we are able to track the sales?

Or is there any platform/solution that could solve this issue? Thank you.